# Unable to render BorderRadius inside Animated Container

Tags: flutter, border, animatedcontainer

I am trying to render circular borderRadius inside animated container. It renders on a Container's shadow but not on the actual container. any Suggestions?

Here's my code:

**Main.dart**

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [Menu(), HomeScreen()],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**HomeScreen.Dart**

I've commented the line of code which is not rendering.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  double xOffset = 0;
  double yOffset = 0;
  double scaleFactor = 1;
  bool _isMenuOpen = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer( 
        transform: Matrix4.translationValues(xOffset, yOffset, 0)
          ..scale(scaleFactor)
          ..rotateY(_isMenuOpen ? -0.5 : 0),
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.black38, offset: Offset(-80,0), spreadRadius: -40)],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(_isMenuOpen ? 40 : 0.0),  //.. this line of code is not rendering
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            AppBar(
              title: Text(
                'Menu Widget',
                style: GoogleFonts.kaushanScript(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              leading: _isMenuOpen
                  ? IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.black),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          xOffset = 0;
                          yOffset = 0;
                          scaleFactor = 1;
                          _isMenuOpen = false;
                        });
                      })
                  : IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.more_horiz,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          xOffset = 270;
                          yOffset = 110;
                          scaleFactor = 0.7;
                          _isMenuOpen = true;
                        });
                      }),
            ),
            HomePageLayout(),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

[[image: 1][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmAt5.png)

The container is inside Menu Dash board. It the Mini HomeScreen on the right, borderRadius is square instead of circular.

Comment: it works just fine: `class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_FooState createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
var r = 0.0;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return AnimatedContainer(
duration: 1000.milliseconds,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(r),
color: r == 0?  Colors.orange : Colors.red,
boxShadow: kElevationToShadow[2],
),
child: GestureDetector(
onTap: () => setState(() => r = (r == 0)? 32 : 0)
),
);
}
}`

Comment: and? is `BorderRadius` rendered?